# 2d array: Why ptr and *ptr are same when i declared ptr as int ptr[4][4];?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was testing some codes to find out how 2d array is implemented in c.
Then I met following problem.

The code is:

```
int main(){
   int a[4][4];
   printf("a: %p, *a: %p, **a: 0x%x\n",a,*a,**a);
}
```

I compiled this with 32-bit ubuntu gcc

The result was:

> a: 0xbf9d6fdc, *a: 0xbf9d6fdc, **a: 0x0

I expected different value for `a` and `*a`, but they are same.

1. why `a` and `*a` are same in this case?
   Is not `a` a `int**` type?
2. Then what is role of `*`operator in `*a`?

Comment: *"Is not `a` a `int**` type?"* In no case whatsoever is there an `int **` in *any* of this. Wherever you read/inferred/were-told that, they're wrong.

Comment: Note you should technically cast the arguments corresponding to a `%p` formatter to `void*`. On most architectures, passing any pointer type will have the same effects, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Doing `**a` may invoke undefined behaviour as it evaluates to `a[0][0]` which has not been initialised/set before.

Comment: @alk Pedantically, `a` has its address taken and cannot be declared with `register` qualifier. On mainstream systems without exotic trap representations, this means that the variable takes an unspecified value, but it is not UB. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the types!!

Given the definition as `int a[4][4];`

- `a` is of type `int [4][4]` - array of an array of 4 integers. It's **not** the same as `int **`.
- `a[n]` is of type `int [4]` - array of 4 integers. It's **not** the same as `int *`
- `a[n][m]` is of type `int`. - integer.

Now, given the fact, that the address of the array is also the address of the first element in the array, the values are same, but they differ in types.

To check it visually

```
int a[4][4]

      +-------+--------+-------+-----------+
      |       |        |       |           |
      |a[0][0]| a[0][1]| a[0][2]   a[0][3] |
      |       |        |       |           |
      +------------------------------------+
      |       |        |       |           |
      |a[1][0]|        |       |           |
      |       |        |       |           |
      +------------------------------------+
      |       |        |       |           |
      |a[2][0]|        |       |           |
      |       |        |       |           |
      +------------------------------------+
      |       |        |       |           |
      |       |        |       |           |
      |       |        |       |           |
      |       |        |       |           |
      +-------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Then, quoting the `C11`, §6.3.2.1

> *Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]*

So, while passing an argument of type array as a function argument, it decays to the pointer to the first element of the array.

So, let's have a look.

- `a`, decays to `&(a[0])` - the address of the first element of type `int (*)[4]`.
- `*a`, which is the same as `a[0]`, decays to an `int *`, pointer to the first element.
- `**a` which is same as `*(*a)` == `*(a[0])` == `a[0][0]` - that's the `int` value at that index.

Now once again look carefully at the image above - do you see that the first element of `int [0]` and `int [0][0]` are basically residing at the same ***address***? In other words, the starting address are the same.

That's the reason behind the output you see.

Comment: I inferred `a` as a pointer type since `[]` , `*` operator works same for `int**` and `int arr[][]` in most case. Thanks for resolving my misunderstanding.

Comment: @DongRyeong I've added some elaboration, hope that helps.